# CouchDB synching to DRUPAL

Tags: drupal-7, couchdb, data-synchronization

I have two questions.  One is synching data from COUCHDB to drupal via FEEDS or SERVCES module. Probably FEEDS. I was thinking I could do a restful GET, that returns JSON from couchDB. But I am confused on how I can select only the dirty records to synch.  Is there a Time stamp, or sequential index number?  The use case is... I want to give these apps to users who interact with the device, and record the activity. This synch's back to the CLOUD.  The alternative would be POSTING data directly from mobile devices to DRUPAL, but drupal can choke... so I would prefer to just goto a CouchDB system.

My second question is just the opposite. I want to post data that changes everyday to mobile devices.  The data is formatted as catalogs in DRUPAL... I would push the DRUPAL data to the COUCH system, and have couch synch data to devices.  Could I get some strategies for this please.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use CouchDB's changes feed:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/changes.html